# Stack Overflow CV is not showing all the open source projects

Tags: bug

I have four open source projects listed when I edit my CV, but only two of them are showing in the public CV. I have tried updating all of them, but nothing seems to work.

UPDATE: I removed all and added all again. It looks like only top three are being selected and if I delete one from the top three then it does not get updated.